# How to put following sentence in proper manner.

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

I am preparing my resume and I have hard time describing one of my work experience.

I have one of the experience in which I was working to company "Z" through company "Y" under the payroll of company "X".

basically, you join company x, then they deploy you in company y and then again they deploy u in company z.

One of the sentence I was trying to compile was

As a Senior Executive, some name was working with company x under the client y of company z

I just don't feel this is a correct way to express this chain of companies. Thank you for helping me out on this.

Comment: First off, you need to practice proper spelling and punctuation.  And you were working as a "contractor".

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid clogging your resume with this kind of detail. It just slides off the brain of the reader without sinking in, and it bogs everything down.

Just pick the best company, the most relevant one, the most impressive one, and go with that. If you are ever questioned, you can always elaborate (enthusiastically -- "Yes! What a great job! I was working with A ... ")